# What is the simplest way to "cast" a member function pointer to a function pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, member

I want to provide a member function for the "comp" parameter of an STL algorithm like lower_bound( ..., Compare comp ).  The comp() function accesses a non-static member field so it must itself be a non-static member but the type of a non-static member function pointer is different from that of an ordinary function pointer.

What is the best way around this problem?

Comment: The term you want to google is "functor"

Comment: or a function object, or with C++11, a lambda/anonymous function :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the most common use of `std::mem_fun` and `std::mem_fun_ref`. They're templates that create functors that invoke the specified member function. TR1 adds an `std::tr1::bind` that's also useful and more versatile (and if you don't have TR1 available, that's based on [`Boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bind/bind.html)). C++0x will include `std::bind` in the standard library (virtually unchanged from TR1).

Comment: mem_fun() works only with functions having one or no parameter, whereas comp must point to a function with two parameters.

Is this functionality available in Qt?

Comment: `mem_fun` also doesn't work with functions that have reference parameters :( If you use `mem_fun_ref` and then try to combine it with `bind1st` or `bind2nd`, it fails again because they are just broken. I recommend to completely change to `boost::bind` and `boost::function`

Comment: For those who are coming late to this page, like me: avoid using `mem_fun` and `mem_fun_ref` which are deprecated; switch to `mem_fn`. *Details:* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680807/stdmem-fun-vs-stdmem-fn

Comment: Or even better, in the OP's case, use a lambda function.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want something like `boost::bind`, to bind the member function pointer to a instance of that class.

Would you care to elaborate your question a bit as to what you're trying to do? Example code, etc.?

Comment: Boost bind is definitely the most flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<tr1/functional>
```

and use mem_fn()