# How can I solve this ambiguousity wrt. mem_fun?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, mem-fun

To practice, one of the topics I'm familiarizing myself with again is trees. The thing about depth-first search and breadth-first search is that they differ only in the choice of the data structure that backs the algorithm.

I thought I could write a common tree search that I would feed either a stack (DFS) or a queue (BFS) using templates. `stack` and `queue` are nice enough that their adding and removing members have the same name. Unfortunately, the access function is once called `top` and `front` for the other. Because of this I did no quite arrive where I wanted. I didn't manage to do it without that lambda:

```
template<typename T, typename D, typename G>
bool ts(Tree<T> const & tree, T const value, D & ds, G getter)
{
    if (empty(tree))
    {
        return false;
    }

    ds.push(tree.Root);
    while (!ds.empty())
    {
        auto const current = getter();
        ds.pop();

        if (current->Value == value)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (current->Left)
        {
            ds.push(current->Left);
        }
        if (current->Right)
        {
            ds.push(current->Right);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
bool dfs(Tree<T> const & tree, T const value)
{
    stack<typename Tree<T>::Node const * const> ds;
    return ts(tree, value, ds, [&ds](){ return ds.top(); });
}

template<typename T>
bool bfs(Tree<T> const & tree, T const value)
{
    queue<typename Tree<T>::Node const * const> ds;
    return ts(tree, value, ds, [&ds](){ return ds.front(); });
}
```

I though that I should be able to use `mem_fun` (or `mem_fun_ref`) to provide the respective access function. I tried

```
template<typename T>
bool dfs(Tree<T> const & tree, T const value)
{
    typedef stack<typename Tree<T>::Node const * const> DataStructure;
    return ts(tree, value, DataStructure(), mem_fun(&DataStructure::top));
}
```

But then the compiler complains about ambiguousity (between a `const` and a non-`const` version).

So I searched the internets and learned that I should provide the template type explicitly.

```
template<typename T>
bool dfs(Tree<T> const & tree, T const value)
{
    typedef stack<typename Tree<T>::Node const * const> DataStructure;
    return ts(tree, value, DataStructure(), mem_fun</*???*/>(&DataStructure::top));
}
```

Sadly, none of the many possibilities for **???** that I could come up with satisfied the compiler.

Can someone give me a hint?

---

**Update:** Here a full working example (except if you define NO_LAMBDA):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Tree
{
    struct Node
    {
        T Value;
        Node * Left;
        Node * Right;

        Node(T value) : Value(value), Left(nullptr), Right(nullptr) {}

        virtual ~Node()
        {
            if (Left) delete Left;
            if (Right) delete Right;
        }
    };

    Node * Root;

    Tree() : Root(nullptr) {}

    virtual ~Tree() { if (Root) delete Root; }
};

template<typename T> void insert(typename Tree<T>::Node * node, T const & value)
{
    typename Tree<T>::Node ** selected = &(value < node->Value ? node->Left : node->Right);

    if (*selected)
        insert(*selected, value);
    else
        *selected = new typename Tree<T>::Node(value);
}

template<typename T> void insert(Tree<T> & tree, T value)
{
    if (!tree.Root)
        tree.Root = new typename Tree<T>::Node(value);
    else
        insert(tree.Root, value);
}

template<typename T, typename D, typename G>
bool ts(Tree<T> const & tree, T const value, D & ds, G getter)
{
    if (!tree.Root) return false;

    ds.push(tree.Root);
    while (!ds.empty())
    {
        auto const current = getter();
        ds.pop();

        if (current->Value == value) return true;

        if (current->Left) ds.push(current->Left);
        if (current->Right) ds.push(current->Right);
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
bool dfs(Tree<T> const & tree, T const value)
{
    typedef typename Tree<T>::Node const * DataStructureContent;
    typedef stack<DataStructureContent> DataStructure;
#ifdef NO_LAMBDA // With this defined, it breaks.
    return ts(tree, value, DataStructure(),
        mem_fun(static_cast<DataStructureContent (DataStructure::*)() const>(&DataStructure::top)));
#else // This works.
    DataStructure ds;
    return ts(tree, value, ds, [&ds] () { return ds.top(); });
#endif
}

int main()
{
    Tree<int> tree;
    insert(tree, 5);
    insert(tree, 2); insert(tree, 1); insert(tree, 3);
    insert(tree, 7); insert(tree, 6); insert(tree, 9);
    cout << "DFS(7) -> " << dfs(tree, 7) << endl;
    cout << "DFS(8) -> " << dfs(tree, 8) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you produce a short complete example?

Comment: Btw, you are binding an lvalue reference (`D& ds` in `ts()`) to an rvalue (`DataStructure()` in `dsf()`). If the compiler accepts it, that is bad. You shouldn't do it.

Comment: Note in general taking pointers to C++ library member functions is not portable, since library implementations are allowed to add additional parameters with default arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast the member function pointer to the type you need:

```
mem_fun( static_cast< R (DataStructure::*)( Args... ) >( &DataStructure::top ) )
```

or

```
mem_fun( static_cast< R (DataStructure::*)( Args... ) const >( &DataStructure::top ) )
```

with appropriate `R` for the result type and `Args...` for the arguments.

**EDIT:** You made two (three) mistakes in your complete example:

a) The cast needs to be exact, that is you need to provide the correct return type. Luckily, `std::stack` has typedefs to help you with that. In your case, you can cast with these two options:

```
typedef typename DataStructure::reference (DataStructure::*non_const_top)();
mem_fun( static_cast< non_const_top >( &DataStructure::top ) )
```

or

```
typedef typename DataStructure::const_reference (DataStructure::*const_top)() const;
mem_fun( static_cast< const_top >( &DataStructure::top ) )
```

b) You tried to bind a temporary to a reference when calling `ts`. Together with a), change the code to:

```
DataStructure ds;
typedef typename DataStructure::reference (DataStructure::*non_const_top)();
return ts(tree, value, ds, mem_fun(static_cast<non_const_top>(&DataStructure::top)));
```

c) In `ts`, you try to call the `getter` without an object. You need to change it to:

```
auto const current = getter( &ds );
```

With these changes, the code works for me.

Comment: I added a full solution with your suggestion, at least as I understood it, doesn't work. The error is given in Nawaz' answer.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about *c*, should have put a comment there. But I never got that far.

Answer (score 2):

Define few typedefs as:

```
typedef typename DataStructure::reference       reference;
typedef typename DataStructure::const_reference const_reference;

typedef reference (DataStructure::*top_type)();             //non-const version
typedef const_reference (DataStructure::*ctop_type)() const;//const version
```

then use whatever you need it.

In the posted code, you need const version, so write this:

```
mem_fun( static_cast<ctop_type>(&DataStructure::top ))
```

The casting helps compiler to choose the version you intend to use.

By the way, in C++11, `std::mem_fun` is **deprecated**. And it has added another function called `std::mem_fn`. Notice the difference in the spelling. See this topic for details:

- [std::mem_fun vs std::mem_fn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680807/stdmem-fun-vs-stdmem-fn)

---

What you need is called `std::bind`, not `std::mem_fun` (or `std::mem_fn`) :

It works now:

- [Online Demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=88f50b5f7e3e4d1e94de019640326075-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94)

The way you're calling `getter` suggests that you need `std::bind` because you're invoking `getter` like this:

```
auto const current = getter();
```

That is an error if `getter` is an object returned from `std::mem_fun`, in which case it should be invoked like this:

```
auto const current = getter(&ds);
```

See this demo:

- [Online Demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d764365d5460991ace4d8f9ebe6b685f-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94)

Or if you simply pass the pointer-to-member, then you invoke as:

```
auto const current = (ds.*getter)();
```

See : [Online Demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=aa7c828018df318ab3b6d53b75ecb538-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94)

Compare all three. See the differences!

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good point with `mem_fn`, but it seems, my STL doesn't have that one, yet.

Comment: @primfaktor: which version of which compiler are you using? If you using GCC, try compiling your code with `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x`) option.

Comment: Tried your and the solution of Daniel. Got neither working. Clang (in this case) always complains about “address of overloaded function 'top'” not being staticly castable.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @primfaktor: In your edited post, you're doing two different things in  `#ifdef` and `#else` part. In one, you're passing `DataStructure()` (which is temporary object), and in the other you're passing `ds`. Treat the same branch in the same way, except the last argument.

Comment: That's right, I do. I like the temporary object more—especially when thinking about rvalue references—but int the `#else` case I have no other choice but to create it beforehand. Because I need to be able to capture it.

Comment: But of course I could have a non-temporary instance on both cases. But it doesn't make a difference wrt. the error.

Comment: @primfaktor: In that case, you should post the error, indicating the line numbers the source code.

Comment: @primfaktor: You did some blunder in your code. I fixed all. See my edited answer. I also demonstrated the alternative syntax, and approaches.

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd is was I was shooting for. I knew that I would have to change the call to *getter* somehow, but I didn't get that far. But some weird syntax in the 3rd. <:-| I'm going to accept Daniel's answer as it is equally good but both first answer and enlightening edit were earlier. Thank you anyway!