# Can I pass a member function to mu::Parser::DefineFun()?

Tags: c++, boost, c++98, muparser

I'm using [muParser](http://muparser.beltoforion.de/) to parse mathematical expressions, and I would like to add a function to the parser whose implementation will be provided by a non-static member function of a class. This excerpt from [an example program](https://gist.github.com/diazona/c03e80227f39cbdc4937) should give an idea of what I want to do:

```
struct MyClass { // some boilerplate omitted
    double make_a_value(double a,  double b); // implemented elsewhere
};

int main(const int argc, const char** argv) {
    MyClass instance;
    mu::Parser p;
    p.DefineFun("f", MORE_MAGIC(MyClass::make_a_value, &instance));
    p.SetExpr("f(3, 2)");
    std::cout << p.Eval() << std::endl;
}
```

where `MORE_MAGIC(...)` stands for something with the signature `double f(double arg1, double arg2)` which is equivalent to calling `instance->make_a_value(arg1, arg2)`. I don't know what `MORE_MAGIC` should be in order for this to work. That's the essence of my question.

The second argument of `DefineFun` can have any of the following function signatures:

- `double f()`
- `double f(double)`
- `double f(double, double)`
- and so on up to 10 `double` arguments
- `double f(double*, int)` where the first pointer is an array and the `int` is its length
- `double f(const char*)`
- `double f(const char*, double)`
- `double f(const char*, double)`

Unfortunately none of these include a `void*` data parameter that I can use to pass in an instance. It occurred to me to subvert a `double*` to pass the instance, but the problem is really that muParser doesn't let me pre-define a value to be passed to the function at all; only the arguments taken from the parsed expression get passed.

From reading several other posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17305134/56541), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3287096/56541), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11680807/56541), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402385/56541), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/282372/56541)) t seems that what I need is a bound function, and the preferred way to do it (in C++98) is `boost::bind`. But I've tried replacing `MORE_MAGIC(...)` with `boost::bind(&wrapper, _1, _2, &instance)`, with

```
double wrapper(double a, double b, MyClass* p) {
    return p->make_a_value(a, b);
}
```

(hopefully correct syntax) and I get compiler errors:

```
/usr/include/muParserBase.h:134:95: error: no matching function for call to ‘mu::ParserCallback::ParserCallback(boost::_bi::bind_t<double, double (*)(double, double, MyClass*), boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<MyClass*> > >&, bool&)’
       AddCallback( a_strName, ParserCallback(a_pFun, a_bAllowOpt), m_FunDef, ValidNameChars() );
```

and so on. Ick.

I guess the problem is that `boost::bind` returns a `boost::function`, whereas I need a standard function, and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453616/56541) it's more or less impossible to get a standard function from a `boost::function` without some `void*` to stash the instance pointer. But I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly, having little experience with Boost, so my preliminary question is: can anyone confirm that `boost::bind` simply *will not* do what I need it to do?

And my main question: is there *any* way at all to accomplish this? Even if it involves arcane secrets of C++ wizardry? (Or **gasp** switching to C++11?)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the muParser API sadly isn't ready for C++.

In C++11 Lambdas can "decay" to function pointers, but this means they have to be stateless, so, you're back at the same spot: you can't bind extra parameters.

Is muParser open source? Perhaps there is a fork that has already amended this design flaw

---

Oh and, yes, `boost::bind` cannot <strike>break the laws of physics</strike> do this for you

Comment: Yes, it is open source and there are a couple forks I know about so I'll take a look and see if they can do that. If not, maybe I should just add the feature myself.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty glaring design flaw anyways, right there on this comprehensive list https://gist.github.com/rmartinho/3176551 (mmm. actually, that's not on the list. Maybe there's a separate one for C API's...?)

Comment: Does [this](https://code.google.com/p/muparser/issues/detail?id=10) mean that the muParser developers have refused to help with this issue?

Comment: @crayzeewulf Wow. It certainly looks like that. I'm appalled, because I thought it was a universal hallmark of bad API design to _not_ provide userdata `void*` arguments ... o.O

Comment: @sehe The least they can do is allow callbacks wrapped in [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). This will solve a lot of issues associated with using muParser with C++. But that will add dependency on C++11 and the developers may not be interested in this.

Comment: That's for a C++ API. I don't know much about their project. And it amounts to the same in more modern vein